# How do I do hanging indents in Context?

Tags: indentation, context

How do I do hanging indents in Context? I've been looking at the few examples that I've found, for example at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/MLA_style, but couldn't get anything to work as I want it. Also the `workscited` function in Context is not my way to go.

I simply want to do a hanging indent, and can't find a straight forward way to do this. Below is a desperate (minimal not working) example trying to use TeX `hangindent`.

```
\setupindenting[1em]
\setuppapersize[A5][A5]


\starttext
\indenting[yes, next] % turn on regular indenting of first line of paragraph, excluding the first paragraph

\subject{A normal section}

This paragraph is not indented since it is the first one!

Hello and miau, this is the second paragraph that is indented by exactly one em, isn't it?

\subject{Works cited}

% We want those to be indented hanging: The first line should begin at the margin while following lines of each paragraph is indented by one em.

\hangindent=1em
\hangafter=1

Jaynes, Julian. {\os 1990}. {\em The Origin of Consciousness in the Breakdown of the Bicameral Mind}. New York City: Houghton Mifflin Company.

Pye, David. {\os 1995}. {\em The Nature and Art of Workmanship}. London: The Herbert Press.

Persson, Tomas. {\os 2008}. {\em Pictorial Primates: A Search for Iconic Abilities in Great Apes}. Lund: Lund University Cognitive Studies.

\stoptext
```

Would be grateful for any help with this! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ConTeXt environments like `definition`, `enumeration`, `list`, etc. provide a key for controlling hanging, but there is no environment that sets hanging for all paragraphs.

Setting the TeX primitive `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` the way you do does not work because TeX resets the hanging indent at each paragraph! So to set hanging indent for **one** paragraph, remove the blank spaces after the `\hang...` macros. So

```
\hangindent=1em
\hangafter=1
% No new paragraph here!
Jaynes, Julian. {\os 1990}. {\em The Origin of Consciousness in the Breakdown of the Bicameral Mind}. New York City: Houghton Mifflin Company.
```

So, if you want hanging indent for multiple paragraphs, use

```
\EveryPar{\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em\relax}
```

In either case disable normal indentation using `\setupindenting[no]`

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101818/what-is-the-correct-way-to-end-a-hanging-indent-section-in-context) contains additional info about **ending** a hanging indent in Context + some other suggestions about doing the indent itself.