# What is the correct way to end a hanging indent section in Context?

Tags: indentation, context

In an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96020/how-do-i-do-hanging-indents-in-context) I got help to get hanging indents working in my text.

I now suspect that I've not been terminating the hanging indent in the right way. Have tried some different things, but still can't get back the regular indent after the hanging indent section.

Looking forward to any clues!

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\starttext

\everypar{\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em\relax} % Comment out this line and it works

\subject{Section with hanging indent}

Jaynes, Julian. {\os 1990}.
{\em The Origin of Consciousness in the
Breakdown of the Bicameral Mind}. New York City: Houghton Mifflin Company.

Pye, David. {\os 1995}. {\em The Nature and Art of Workmanship}.
London: The Herbert Press.

\everypar{\hangafter=0\relax} % Comment out this line and it works

\setupindenting[yes, next, 9mm]
\subject{Section with regular identing}
I would expect this line to begin at the margin,
not having an indent \ldots\ and so is the case, but only
if I delete the above {\em Section with hanging indent}.

This next paragraph would be intented.
\stoptext
```

Comment: In general, do not use `\everypar` in ConTeXt. Use `\EveryPar` instead.

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104293/what-is-the-difference-between-everypar-and-everypar) regarding `\everypar` versus `\EveryPar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> still can't get back the regular indent after the hanging indent section.

Firstly, if you want to stick with your workaround, you should
make the modifications to indentation local.
To do so, just wrap them into a group:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\starttext

\bgroup
\everypar{\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em\relax}

\subject{Section with hanging indent}

Jaynes, Julian. {\os 1990}.
{\em The Origin of Consciousness in the
Breakdown of the Bicameral Mind}. New York City: Houghton Mifflin Company.

Pye, David. {\os 1995}. {\em The Nature and Art of Workmanship}.
London: The Herbert Press.

\everypar{\hangafter=0\relax}
\egroup

\setupindenting[yes,first, 9mm]
\subject{Section with regular identing}
I would expect this line to begin at the margin,
not having an indent \ldots\ and so is the case, but only
if I delete the above {\em Section with hanging indent}.

This next paragraph would be intented.
\stoptext
```

This way the original indentation behavior should return.

However, may I suggest you use the high-level Context interface
instead?
The inverted indentation can be achieved by combining a couple
ordinary macros (at least as far as the example you gave is
concerned), and the code certainly looks a bit more idiomatic.
I’ll call the environment *negindent* for “negative indentation”.

```
\definestartstop [negindent] [
  before={%
    \startnarrower[left]%
    \setupindenting[-\leftskip,yes,first]%
    \setuphead[subject][indentnext=yes]%
  },
  after=\stopnarrower,
]

\setuppapersize[A5]

\starttext
  \startnegindent % ····················································%
    \subject{Section with hanging indent}

    Jaynes, Julian. {\os 1990}.
    {\em The Origin of Consciousness in the
    Breakdown of the Bicameral Mind}. New York City: Houghton Mifflin Company.

    Pye, David. {\os 1995}. {\em The Nature and Art of Workmanship}.
    London: The Herbert Press.
  \stopnegindent % ·····················································%

  \setupindenting[yes, next, 9mm]
  \subject{Section with regular identing}
  I would expect this line to begin at the margin,
  not having an indent \ldots\ and so is the case, but only
  if I delete the above {\em Section with hanging indent}.

  This next paragraph would be intented.
\stoptext
```

[image: Demo image]

Update:
In order to make this work with MkII, the indenting has to be
registered in advance:

```
\defineindentingmethod [negative] {\parindent-\leftskip}

\definestartstop [negindent] [
  before={%
    \startnarrower[left]%
    \setupindenting[yes,first,negative]%
    \setuphead[subject][indentnext=yes]%
  },
  after=\stopnarrower,
]
```

Comment: Thanks, can confirm that the first solution works perfectly! But I'm also very interested in the later one. However I get a `l.13   \startnegindent` when trying to compile the MWE. I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) and ConTeXt version 2012.05.30 11:26 MKII fmt: 2012.12.8, but guess it has do to with my installation in some way?

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver
I appended a snippet that works with MkII.
Is there a reason as to why you still work with the legacy
format?
You’ll be running into tons of these situations.

Comment: No, there's no reason for that except I didn't know I was :) I have to read up on the versions of Context and move over!

Comment: How to use ConTeXt MkIV in TeXworks: If you have the latest TeX Live release you should just make sure TeXworks runs **ConTeXt (LuaTeX)** as default and ConTeXt MkIV will be used as standard.