# What is the difference between \everypar and \EveryPar?

Tags: context, paragraphs

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101818/what-is-the-correct-way-to-end-a-hanging-indent-section-in-context#comment222954_101818) I got recommended to use `\EveryPar` instead of `\everypar`.

What is the difference between the two?

Are there other commands that I should capitalize the same way in ConTeXt?

Comment: I don't know much about ConTeXt, but I guess that `\EveryPar` provides some interface for using the primitive `\everypar` that's not so easy to deal with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `syst-aux.mkiv`:

> It's common use to use `\everypar` for special purposes. In ConTeXt we use
>   this primitive for locating sidefloats. This means that when user
>   assignments to `\everypar` can interfere with those of the package. We
>   therefore introduce `\EveryPar`.
>
> The same goes for \type `\EveryLine`. Because TeX offers no `\everyline`
>   primitive, we have to call for `\everyline` when we are working on a line by
>   line basis. Just by calling `\EveryPar{}` and `\EveryLine{}` we
>   restore the old situation.