# Package for overlapping marginnotes

Tags: marginpar, marginnote

I am not sure, but I think that I heard about a package that can convert two overlapping `\marginpar` into one paragraph with comma. I need this to use withe the marginpars that are really short.

Does this package exist? What is its name?

Comment: This is possible with the [`reledmac`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledmac?lang=en) package, which is designed for the typesetting of critical editions. Might be overkill for your needs....

Comment: No package, but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305022/how-can-i-put-marginnotes-next-to-each-other/305273?s=5|0.7397#305273

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you, I was looking for something like `\marginmerge`