# How can I combine overlapping marginnotes in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, marginnote

I'm working on a project very similar to the one described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305022/how-can-i-put-marginnotes-next-to-each-other), only for various reasons I'm using ConTeXt rather than that poster's use of XeLaTeX.

I too am typesetting a text with verse/line numbers in the margin and am interested in combining them should there happen to be two that end up on the same line, dividing them with a slash or a comma or something like that.

The comments there allude to a possible solution in ConTeXt with the possible use of \EveryLine, but I have not yet been able to figure out how to implement a solution using that command - I think I'm a bit newer at various implementations of TeX than the previous questioner!  Is there a reliable way to implement this in ConTeXt?

EDITED TO ADD:

A very simple MWE:

```
\starttext

\inmargin{1}Now we are engaged in a great civil war.
\inmargin{2}We are testing whether that nation or any nation so conceived 
and so dedicated, can long endure.
\inmargin{3}We are met on a great battle-field of that war.

\stoptext
```

Results in:

[image: The result]

I would like the 1 and 2 not to be overlapping, nor to be stacked like the `\setupmargindata[stack=yes]` would get me, but rather to automatically combine those that would overlap to get something like `"1,2"` that would look like:

[image: Desired output]

I would appreciate any help...thank you!

Comment: In the project I work on we had a similar problem. A colleague of mine solved it by traversing each line of the document with Lua and building a string, that separates each margin datum with a comma. This string is stored in a separate file that is used to run a PERL script with regexes that produce the desired effect. If you're interested, I can write a more detailed answer with code etc. -- but I'd prefer a simpler solution that only relies on ConTeXt, too.

Comment: I have looked at the margin notes code and it appears to me as if it was possible to add this possibility as an alternative to the `stack` option.  It's a good idea to ask about this on the mailing list https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context

Comment: @meliade I would be quite interested in your solution. Are you still willing to write up an answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has lost interest in the question.

Comment: @Sebastiano - I haven't actually lost interest in it; I've simply hit a wall.  I went over to the mailing list and found no help there: https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/thread/6EIPU7IFETY3FKSTBRUXCPJ2SSX3GBMI/  If anything changes, I'd still be interested in hearing more about it!

Comment: @Benjamin It is an old question. I think no one will control it. Excuse me for closing it. I will be the first to reopen it.