# How to modify \everypar safely in a package?

Tags: tex-core, latex-base

This is a follow-up to [What does the \the\everypar do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33849) and [TikZ Overlay: Inject content at the start of the next paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509059)

From a quick `grep -R '\\everypar' texmf-dist/tex/latex` I can see that `\everypar` is used extensively in different packages. Is there a safe, agreed-upon way how to use `\everypar` to prepend some content to some paragraphs **without** breaking other packages in the process? I read that [ConTeXt has `\EveryPar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104293/what-is-the-difference-between-everypar-and-everypar), but I assume that doesn't exist in LaTeX.

Essentially I'd like to create a macro which prepends something only to the *next* paragraph started after it is called, but *without* breaking other packages along the way.

For example, is it possible to insert a custom hook into the token list, and remove it again later--while hoping that other packages don't clear the token list when you're not looking? Or is there no such thing in TeX/LaTeX?

Comment: The problem is, that many LaTeX internals might set `\everypar` and later reset it to be empty, for example every heading uses `\@afterheading`, which sets `\everypar` to prevent a page break after a heading and remove the first indent, and this doesn't append or prepend anything but just sets the entire `\everypar`, so you can't be sure that anything remains in `\everypar`. What do you want to achieve anyway?

Comment: @Skillmon: The details are in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509059. But essentially I want to create a macro which just prepends something to the *next* paragraph started after it is called, and *without* breaking other packages along the way. It doesn't really matter if the content stays in there for a long time.

Comment: Wrapfigure saves the contents of \everypar as a token list.  You might look at how ithat package does it.

Comment: Why can't you just put your prepended stuff at the start of the paragraph?

Comment: @PeterWilson Because sometimes the next paragraph starts in a different file. For example: `\PrependToNextPar{something} \include{some-figure.tex}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way is probably to use an inline heading eg the following which puts **Zzzzz** into the start of the following paragraph and then cleans up `\everypar` it does this in a way that works even if the paragraph starts in a group, as here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Zzzzz}

\showthe\everypar

{abc}


{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Technically this is a making a local definition of `\@svsechd` with the code you want to insert and setting some booleans to control the behaviour.

There are other ways of setting and restoring `\everypar` but any package that is messing with start of paragraph should (hopefully) already be detecting this first paragraph of a section case and doing the right thing, so I would either directly use `\paragraph` or a similar command using the `\@startsection` mechanism, or at least to copy enough of the definition shown by the `\show\everypar` if you run the above that your code looks to other packages like a standard latex run-in heading.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `\paragraph`. I forgot that there is a command available which does something very similar to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future readers, I'd like to refer to [this LaTeX3 solution proposed by cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326947/12440) in a similar question:

```
\usepackage{l3galley,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_galley_par_begin_hook_tl
{
  Any stuff that you want to put at the beginning of a paragraph.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```